Problema sumando meses a las fechas
Tengo un problema con las fechas.
Si por ejemplo a la fecha 30/03/2022 le sumo 6 meses, se me va a 30/09/2022.
Todo correcto.
as.Date("30/03/2022", format = "%d/%m/%Y") + months(6)
"2022-09-30"

Pero si hago lo mismo con la fecha 31/03/2022 me da error pq no existe el 31/09/2022.
    as.Date("31/03/2022", format = "%d/%m/%Y") + months(6)
    NA

Lo que quiero es que me diera como fecha el día siguiente.  01/10/2022.
No sé si hay una librería diseñada o alguna forma de sumar meses que tenga en cuenta todos los posibles casos donde esto ocurra, ya sea sumandole 6, 7, 9 o los meses que sean.

Lo que puedes hacer es una función que genere una secuencia de fechas por mes y quedarnos con la fecha del mes esperado:
addmonth <- function(d, m) {
 seq(d, by="month", length.out=m+1)[m+1]
}

ejemplo:
addmonth(as.Date("31/03/2022", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 6)
[1] "2022-10-01"

Si quieres trabajar con un vector puedes perfectamente hacer algo así:
addmonth <- function(dl, m) {
  as.Date(sapply(dl, FUN=function(d) {
    seq(d, by="month", length.out=m+1)[[m+1]]
  }))
}


fechas <- seq(as.Date("31/03/2022", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
              by="day", length.out=15)

addmonth(fechas, 6)

 [1] "2022-10-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-10-02" "2022-10-03"
 [5] "2022-10-04" "2022-10-05" "2022-10-06" "2022-10-07"
 [9] "2022-10-08" "2022-10-09" "2022-10-10" "2022-10-11"
[13] "2022-10-12" "2022-10-13" "2022-10-14"


El problema es que no tengo una fecha, tengo una lista de fechas. Tendría que haberlo puesto en el ejemplo. Intentaré retocar el código.  La solución Jilber Urbina si funciona para listas.

Claro, igualmente no es muy complejo reconvertir la función al trabaj ocon un vector, ahi edité mi respuesta

O sin reconvertir la función, bastaría con iterar sobre el vector de fechas usando tu función original así: sapply(fechas, addmonth, 6)|> as.Date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")

En términos de meses, lo mejor es que te de el día anterior si la fecha no existe, ya que la diferencia en diferencias en meses sería 6 (lo deseado), si te da el día siguiente y este se pasa al mes siguiente, como es tu caso, la diferencia en meses sería 7 y no 6. Si esto te resulta lógico, entonces podés valorar la siguiente alternativa:
> library(lubridate)
> ymd("2022/03/31") %m+% months(6)
[1] "2022-09-30"

